# Unable to use execvp to run a python3 file from a C file? (macOS)

Tags: python, c

In the code below, I'm trying to execute an existing python file (the python file is fine), while passing an argument, using execvp. For some reason I'm unable to. Also worth mentioning that I'm running this on macOSX.

I'm passing the argument from terminal like this:

```
#./run testArg
```

I've already tried

```
   execlp("python3", "python3", "./test.py", NULL);
   execlp("python3", "python3", "./test.py", args);
   execlp("python3", "python3", "./test.py", argv);
```

`s.t args` is:
       `char** const args[] = {argv}`;

The top one works (but obviously no argument), the bottom two don't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <Python/Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char** const args[] = {argv};
  execvp("./test.py", args);
```

Comment: I don't understand the "char** const args[] = {argv};"  - I'm probably still using C from 2 decades ago - but having just looked at "man execvp" why aren't you just calling...
"execvp(".test.py", argv+1)"?

Comment: Well eitherway, execvp isn't executing the python file properly, I'm assuming it has something to do with the python3 file location in macOS (because I'm fairly certain this exact code compiled fine on a linux machine). But I can't for the life of me seem to figure this out. 
In execlp it was an easy get around because I can just do execlp("python3", "python3", file.py, NULL). But execvp only takes two arguments

Comment: It might help if you pasted in the errors that you got from each attempt.

Comment: But you are you passing in (the original) argv[0] (i.e. the path to your C program) intentionally?

Comment: execvp simply produces a logical error, I debugged using a printf and found that it simply does not compile the python file; reason being, I'm assuming, is that it's trying to compile the file with python2.7 (default on macOS), whereas it needs to be compiled using python 3.

Comment: @SimonF not sure what you mean, but argv[0] is the path to my c, because that's how I run it (./nameOfProgram.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char** const args[] = {argv};
```

Creates variable that is an array to variables with the type being pointer to pointer to character. The array has *one* element, ie. it stores one element of pointer to pointer to character type. This one element has the *value* of the argv pointer, ie. the value of `&argv[0]` (not `argv[0]`). `args` is an array of variables that have pointer to pointer to character type. `args` is not a "copy of all memory referenced by argv" thing. `args` is a single element array.

```
args
```

In most context array of type decays into pointer of type. So `args` decays to pointer to pointer to pointer to character, ie. is has `char ***` type. Note that to the value `args == &args` and that `args != &argv`. The address of `args` array is not equal to `argv`.

Calling `execvp` with non-compatible arguments is undefined behavior so anything can happen. Enable compiler warnings and fix them every time, so that no undefined behavior happens in your program.

What you want, is that to create a *copy* of all *values* of pointers inside `argv` array. You need also a space for NULL terminator. So first allocate the memory for *values* of all pointers inside `argv` array of `argc` count pointers to strings. Then copy the *values* of pointers inside `argv` array. NULL terminate the array. Then call `execvp`.

```
// allocate space
char **args = calloc(sizeof(char*), argc + 1);
// copy pointers
for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    args[i] = argv[i];
}
// alternatively copy values using memcpy
memcpy(args, argv, sizeof(char*) * argc);
// null terminate
args[argc] = NULL;

execvp("./test.py", args);

// and always remember to pick up the trash
free(args);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm but I had to pass it as 
execvp("./test.py", args[1])